# How to avoid Jenkins think the build is fixed when it builds another branch?

Tags: git, jenkins, branch, jenkins-plugins

We use the `git` plugin to build all the branches of our repo (`Branch specifier` is `**`).

The problem is if branch `A` breaks, we get notified by email.

However, if someone pushed to branch `B` and it builds correctly, then we get a second email telling use "Build back to normal".

But the branch `A` is still broken, yet we think all is good.

Is there a way to make the "email notifier" (and Jenkins) understand that the build is still broken for a branch?

Or is there another approach to build **all branches**, even new ones, automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a build per branch.

First, you should setup a sync job that creates the jobs automatically if a new branch is created.  You will want to use these scripts/plugins: http://entagen.github.io/jenkins-build-per-branch/

Then you will receive notifications per branch instead of the entire repository.  We do this for our project and it works great.  We went a little further and spin up staging environments per branch as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've read about this plugin but I wanted to avoid it (because there's a bit of overhead/clutter with all the builds). But it seems like the only solution.

Comment: The overhead is disk space and cpu usage, but disk space in my opinion should be considered negligible and the cpu usage can be maintained by having less executors.

Comment: Having 10 builds instead of one for CI clutters jenkins interface :( As for the disk space, it may be a problem :( (cheap SSD VPS so not much)

Comment: We run it in Memory - speeds up everything and wipe clean any extraneous builds on branches - keep it around 3 - it helps.  We do have lots of memory though, I will admit that.  We also separate out each tab for branches - this helps clean up the UI.